# Cannot find ImmutableSettingsBuilder with ES 2.1

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to build a elastic search application with ES 2.1.0 server and 2.1.1 Java API client. Below is my pom dependency tree. I am trying to create a transport client using xml configuration. But even before it launches a client i see that it cannot find ImmutableSettingsBuilder class.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-cloud-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

xml configuration:

```
<!-- <elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true"/> -->

 <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-name="elasticsearch_aguruvayya" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300"/>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/settings/ImmutableSettings$Builder

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:129)
```

Comment: I am aware that ImmutableSettings class was removed from ES 2 and above. But i am using SettingsBuilder which is part of the new ES client. But still i see this error. Some implementation is internally trying to use Immutable settings and i am not able to find what it is.

Comment: The problem is that Spring Data Elasticsearch 1.3.2 [depends on Elasticsearch 1.7.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/552a2dd834fbb714d9530b6be428058ebf38eba6/pom.xml#L12). The latest version 1.4.0.SNAPSHOT still depends on ES 1.7.3, so I guess you'll probably need to downgrade ES if you want to go this way, until they update Spring Data ES.